# How do I translate force in one point to another point in an object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, vectors, torque

For a project I need to model a system where a body can pivot at one point, and is lifted up by a piston, to rotate the body around the point.
I am having trouble finding the formulas and ways to calculate all forces at play.

Consider the sketch below:

[image]

Where

- A is the point around which the object can pivot,
- B is the center of mass of the object,
- C is one end of the piston,
- D is the other end of the piston

What I'm looking for is the force applied to the piston, due to gravity pulling down on the object.

My approach to calculating this has been the following:

[image]

1. Calculate the force with which gravity pulls down on the object at the center of mass.

> F_1 = 9.81 * weight of object

2. Translate that force to a torque around the pivoting point with

> t_1 = [distance from A to B] * F_1 * sin(theta_1)

3. Use that torque and calculate the force pulling down in point C

> F_2 = ( t_1 * sin(theta_2) ) / [distance from A to C]

4. The force pushing on the piston would then be equal to

> F_piston = F_2 * sin(beta)

However, I don't think this is very correct. I am assuming t_1 and t_2 are the same, which they are not, I think?
I'm also not sure about step 4, where I determine F_piston out of F_2.

I'm sure it must be possible to calculate the force pushing on the piston. I've never had a class in mechanics, so I don't really what I'm doing or how I can best tackle this issue.

Comment: Hint: Find point **G** where the line of action of the piston and gravity meet. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbY8c.png You will notice that the reaction force at the pivot must also pass through this point and hence can do the force balance there https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpCAi.png

Comment: See [this diagram](https://i.imgur.com/D1PpDhW.png) and resulting equations $$\left.\begin{aligned}F_{C}\cos\theta-F_{A}\cos\psi & =0\\
F_{C}\sin\theta+F_{A}\sin\psi & =mg
\end{aligned}
\right\} \begin{aligned}F_{A} & =\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\left(\psi+\theta\right)}m\,g\\
F_{C} & =\frac{\cos\psi}{\sin\left(\psi+\theta\right)}m\,g
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thank you very much @JohnAlexiou for your answer.
Just for my understanding, What is the meaning of force F_A ?

Comment: Let's say that the object weights 10kg and that ψ = -5° and θ = 15°.
Can I now consider that the force that's pushing on the piston is equal to:
F_C = [ cos(-5°) / sin(-5° + 15°) ] * 10 * 9.81 = 625.167 N
Do you think that makes sense?
How do I interpret this number, I'm wondering what the sign should be. 
I thought the force should have been negative, since the F_C arrow points away from the piston, but I was expecting the force to point into the piston

Comment: $F_A$ is the pivot reaction force. it is the force needed to keep point **A** fixed in space.

Comment: In the diagram, I have included all the forces _acting on the body_ in their positive sense.  $F_C$ is positive meaning it is helping support the weight (has positive _y_ component).

Comment: Also, note that the angles are shown as positive. This means $\psi > 0$ the object is sloped downwards (as shown), and $\psi<0$ the object is sloped upwards (opposite of what is shown).